# npm and node slow to exit on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a build process using npm with several tasks registered in a chain.

package.json looks like this (the http/https stuff is because of a proxy server certificate that upsets npm):

```
  "scripts": {
    "git-config": "git config --global --replace-all url.\"https://\".insteadOf git://",
    "bower-install": "node_modules/.bin/bower install",
    "bower": "npm run git-config && npm run bower-install",
    "build": "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ && npm config set strict-ssl false && npm install && npm run bower && node build-bundles"
  },
```

Every time npm or node is launched, there seems to be about a .5 second hang to launch, and another 1.5 second hang AFTER the command has finished but before the npm/node process exits. In the above script, there are many calls to npm/node, and this ends up adding 15-20 seconds onto our build time (even if there are no changes).

Is there any way to:

- Eliminate at least the 2 second hang before npm/node exits
- Make the above script(s) only execute when one of the project files changes (I do not want to use watchify)
- Otherwise improve the speed of these scripts

Please note that this question doesn't have anything to do with the speed of npm install, package caching, package download speed or the like.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this one ?